# tokio::select! but for a Vec of futures

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I have a `Vec` of futures which I want to execute concurrently (but not necessarily in parallel). Basically, I'm looking for some kind of `select` function that is similar to `tokio::select!` but takes a collection of futures, or, conversely, a function that is similar to `futures::join_all` but returns once the first future is done.

An additional requirement is that once a future finished I might want to add a new future to the `Vec`.

With such a function, my code would roughly look like this:

```rust
use std::future::Future;
use std::time::Duration;
use tokio::time::sleep;

async fn wait(millis: u64) -> u64 {
    sleep(Duration::from_millis(millis)).await;
    millis
}

// This pseudo-implementation simply removes the last
// future and awaits it. I'm looking for something that
// instead polls all futures until one is finished, then
// removes that future from the Vec and returns it.
async fn select<F, O>(futures: &mut Vec<F>) -> O
where
    F: Future<Output=O>
{
    let future = futures.pop().unwrap();
    future.await
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let mut futures = vec![
        wait(500),
        wait(300),
        wait(100),
        wait(200),
    ];
    while !futures.is_empty() {
        let finished = select(&mut futures).await;
        println!("Waited {}ms", finished);
        if some_condition() {
            futures.push(wait(200));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe use streams, i.e. `stream::iter(futures).try_for_each_concurrent` or `future::try_join_all`

Comment: @MartinGallagher That's an interesting idea -- I've posted a prototype as an answer, but it's not really elegant so far.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is exactly what [`futures::stream::FuturesUnordered`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.19/futures/stream/struct.FuturesUnordered.html) is for (which I've found by looking through the source of [`StreamExt::for_each_concurrent`](https://docs.rs/futures/latest/futures/stream/trait.StreamExt.html#method.for_each_concurrent)):

```rust
use futures::{stream::FuturesUnordered, StreamExt};
use std::time::Duration;
use tokio::time::{sleep, Instant};

async fn wait(millis: u64) -> u64 {
    sleep(Duration::from_millis(millis)).await;
    millis
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let mut futures = FuturesUnordered::new();
    futures.push(wait(500));
    futures.push(wait(300));
    futures.push(wait(100));
    futures.push(wait(200));
    
    let start_time = Instant::now();

    let mut num_added = 0;
    while let Some(wait_time) = futures.next().await {
        println!("Waited {}ms", wait_time);
        if num_added < 3 {
            num_added += 1;
            futures.push(wait(200));
        }
    }
    
    println!("Completed all work in {}ms", start_time.elapsed().as_millis());
}
```

([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6f1c36b40c3780dc835785208c0a5315))

A word of caution if you're using Tokio: As [@Bryan Larsen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/91365/bryan-larsen) has [pointed out in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70774671/tokioselect-but-for-a-vec-of-futures/70778511?noredirect=1#comment135609199_70778511), there is the risk of performance problems when combining `FuturesUnordered` with Tokio. [This article](https://www.scylladb.com/2022/01/12/async-rust-in-practice-performance-pitfalls-profiling/) contains more details, and says that the issue should be fixed in recents versions of the `futures` crate (`0.3.19` and later). Nevertheless, users of Tokio are better off with using Tokio's [`JoinSet`](https://docs.rs/tokio/1.32.0/tokio/task/struct.JoinSet.html). The same example as above then looks like this:

```rust
use std::time::Duration;
use tokio::task::JoinSet;
use tokio::time::{sleep, Instant};

async fn wait(millis: u64) -> u64 {
    sleep(Duration::from_millis(millis)).await;
    millis
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let mut futures = JoinSet::new();
    futures.spawn(wait(500));
    futures.spawn(wait(300));
    futures.spawn(wait(100));
    futures.spawn(wait(200));

    let start_time = Instant::now();

    let mut num_added = 0;
    while let Some(result) = futures.join_next().await {
        let wait_time = result.unwrap();
        println!("Waited {}ms", wait_time);
        if num_added < 3 {
            num_added += 1;
            futures.spawn(wait(200));
        }
    }

    println!(
        "Completed all work in {}ms",
        start_time.elapsed().as_millis()
    );
}
```

([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ed9ec82f7cd0e266c78bed08e3e73db2))

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there something similar in tokio ?

Comment: @Charlie木匠 what would be the benefit tokio could bring here ? You can use `futures` crate in a tokio runtime without any issue ;)

Comment: You saved me a lot of time, thank you so much!

Comment: FuturesUnordered has a bunch of foot guns when combined with Tokio.   If you're using Tokio JoinSet is recommended instead.  https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=29911141

Comment: @BryanLarsen Thanks for the info! I've extended my answer to cover `JoinSet` as well.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a working prototype based on streams and `StreamExt::for_each_concurrent`, as Martin Gallagher has [suggested in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70774671/tokioselect-but-for-a-vec-of-futures#comment125119669_70774671):

```rust
use std::time::Duration;
use tokio::sync::RwLock;
use tokio::time::sleep;

use futures::stream::{self, StreamExt};
use futures::{channel::mpsc, sink::SinkExt};

async fn wait(millis: u64) -> u64 {
    sleep(Duration::from_millis(millis)).await;
    millis
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let (mut sink, futures_stream) = mpsc::unbounded();

    let start_futures = vec![wait(500), wait(300), wait(100), wait(200)];

    let num_futures = RwLock::new(start_futures.len());

    sink.send_all(&mut stream::iter(start_futures.into_iter().map(Ok)))
        .await
        .unwrap();

    let sink_lock = RwLock::new(sink);

    futures_stream
        .for_each_concurrent(None, |fut| async {
            let wait_time = fut.await;
            println!("Waited {}", wait_time);
            if some_condition() {
                println!("Adding new future");
                let mut sink = sink_lock.write().await;
                sink.send(wait(100)).await.unwrap();
            } else {
                let mut num_futures = num_futures.write().await;
                *num_futures -= 1;
            }
            let num_futures = num_futures.read().await;
            if *num_futures <= 0 {
                // Close the sink to exit the for_each_concurrent
                sink_lock.write().await.close().await.unwrap();
            }
        })
        .await;
}
```

While this approach works it has the drawback that we need to maintain a separate counter of remaining futures so that we can close the sink -- there's no `Vec` of futures for which we can check whether it's empty. Closing the sink requires another lock.

Given that I'm fairly new to Rust I wouldn't be surprised if this approach could be made more elegant.