# Is there a dynamic alternative to tokio's `select!` macro?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio, rust-futures

I have an application that listens for messages from multiple channels at the same it. If there were a hard-coded amount of channels, this would be trivial. From the tokio docs:

```rs
use tokio::sync::mpsc;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let (tx1, mut rx1) = mpsc::channel(128);
    let (tx2, mut rx2) = mpsc::channel(128);
    let (tx3, mut rx3) = mpsc::channel(128);

    loop {
        let msg = tokio::select! {
            Some(msg) = rx1.recv() => msg,
            Some(msg) = rx2.recv() => msg,
            Some(msg) = rx3.recv() => msg,
            else => { break }
        };

        println!("Got {:?}", msg);
    }

    println!("All channels have been closed.");
}
```

However, I have a vector that may contain any amount of channels, so this is not possible. I'd need something like:

```rs
use tokio::sync::mpsc;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let channels = get_channels(); // Returns Vec<mpsc::Receiver<_>>

    while let Some(msg) = magic_crate::select_dynamic(&channels.iter()).await {
        println!("Got {:?}", msg);
    }

    println!("All channels closed");
}
```

It's  important to note that (I think) `futures::select_all` wouldn't work here because as well as returning the result of the first completing future, the function I'm looking for would also need to cancel the other futures just like `tokio::select!` does in order to make sure that incoming messages from the other channels are not dropped.

Is there any way to do this? Am I wrong about `futures::select_all`? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70774671/tokioselect-but-for-a-vec-of-futures. I don't think `futures::select_all` drops any items in its child streams (I'm pretty sure this would be documented behaviour). It is build on top of `FuturesUnordered` (accepted answer in the question I've linked) by the way.

Comment: From the example, it looks like you should just clone the sender side of the `mpsc`. Then you only have one receiver and the problem disappears.

Comment: @drewtato sorry, bad example. In my actual codebase, I'm using tcp streams so this wouldn't work. Thanks for the idea though

Comment: @JonasFassbender documentation states it would return the result of the first future as well as a list of all the other futures that didn't complete, which makes me think they'd still be executing at that point. How do I guarantee that they're dropped immediately to avoid them receiving a message before they're dropped, which would lead to that message being lost?

Comment: @Jake my bad I meant [`futures::stream::select_all`](https://docs.rs/futures/latest/futures/stream/fn.select_all.html), not [`futures::future::select_all`](https://docs.rs/futures/latest/futures/future/fn.select_all.html)

Comment: @JonasFassbender really? That actually seems farther away from what I want since it returns a stream that will resolve all the futures. Then I'd have to make sure that every time I consume a future from the stream I add a new one replacing it (since I want to keep reading from each channel until it's closed), at which point the borrow checker would probably start acting up... All I really need is a guarantee that all non-completed futures returned from `futures::future::select_all` are dropped immediately.

Comment: @JonasFassbender this is where my knowledge of rust's async behaviours gets a bit fuzzy: If I do `while let (Some(res), _, _) = futures::future::select_all(...)`, does the assigning of the array of remaining futures to `_` (which, AFAIK, drops them (?)) cancel them? My understanding is that this _should_ work, as long as the other futures are non-blocking. If the futures block, I don't know – UB, maybe? Since there's no `#[might_block]` macro (yet) and I apply some library operations to received futures, I can't easily guarantee they don't block and as such, am... confused.